# ¿Por qué la gente se ríe cuando me presento como "Fénix, como el ave"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, saludos, hispanoamérica

Mi nombre es Fénix — muy raro aún en inglés.  Cuando me presento a la gente en Suramérica, a menudo se malinterpreta mi nombre como "Felix".

Entonces, me he acostumbrado presentarme así:  "Soy Fénix, como el ave."

Cada vez lo hago, la otra persona ríe... pero entiende mi nombre correctamente.

Por qué la gente ríe cuando me presento como, "Fénix, como el ave"?

Comment: An uncommon name, and a funny association. Imagine someone approaching you and saying "Tarzán, como el de los monos"

Comment: A mí me haría gracia si alguien se presenta así en inglés, alemán, castellano, francés...

Comment: Compararse con un 'ave' tiene cierta connotación femenina que, viendo por tu foto que eres un hombre, puedes no desear, o al menos, debes ser consciente de ello. En mi opinión no es grave ni denigrante, pero puede ser un factor que añada comicidad al asunto.

Comment: @JoulSauron Tengo que presentarme así en inglés porque si no, la otra persona dirá, "Ohhh, como la capital de Arizona," o peor... "Sí, como el actor!"  Buuu... la leyenda del fénix es mucho más digno :P

Comment: Podrías presentarte como `Fénix, como el caballero del zodiaco` para resultados más hilarantes en quien entienda la referencia

Comment: No le veo la gracia, supongo que escuchan bien el nombre Fénix, sólo que cómo es poco común... Dicen ¿Felix? Por ignorancia, sólo eso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En mi opinión, puede sonar algo gracioso, el hecho de decir la frase en un estilo que tiene un tono teatral. Quizás probando una sutil diferencia, como `Mi nombre es Fénix, como el ave`, o haciendo notar que ya sabes que no es común `Mi nombre es Fénix, sí, como el ave`. De todos modos me parece bueno que como primera impresión la gente siempre sonría.

Comment: "Renace de sus cenizas, como el Ave Fénix", esa frase está grabada en las cabezas de muchos adultos. Ciertamente muy teatral, y es muy similar a "Fénix, como el ave".

Answer (score 7):

Se ríen porque es gracioso. Si quieres evitarlo, otra manera de presentarte sería:

> — Me llamo Fénix.
>
> — ¿Felix?
>
> — No, Fé**n**ix. Con ene.

Comment: +1 Y si por el contrario quieres hacerlo aún más gracioso, puedes agregar : "... como el ave, no como el [gato](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_gato_F%C3%A9lix)"  ;-)

Comment: @leonbloy: jeje.. pues a mi lo primero que se me occure relacionado con nombre Felix es [Felix Leiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Leiter) ;-)

Answer (score 5):

La gente ríe porque simplemente le causa gracia. No es una ofensa, tomatelo con humor :)

People laugh simply because they find it funny. It's not an offense, take it with humor :)

Answer (score 1):

:D lol, me parece muy divertido! de solo imaginarme cuando te presentas pero te aconsejo no te sientas mal, ni lo tomes como ofensa.  Quizás sea un poco del humor "sudamericano" ...

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que el efecto cómico se debe a la significación de la palabra ´ave´, la cual no es ya la misma cosa que el latín *avis*. Según un diccionario que tengo al alcance, ´ave´ es algo como ´poultry´, y ´bird´ es ´pájaro´ como en ´el pájaro que voló´ para un cantante peruano Lisandro Mesa.

¿Porque no dice usted ´como un pájaro de fuego´, o ´como un nebí/neblí/halcón/tagarote/terzuelo/ulive´? Todas las palabras significan la misma cosa: el halcón, o 'the falcon/hauk/tiercel'.

El /x/ castellano no es más dificil a articular que el mismo sonido en el escocés (por ejemplo, en la palabra ´licht´).

Comment: Si la gente ya se sonríe con _Me llamo Fénix, como el ave fénix_, si dice _Me llamo Fénix, como el pájaro de fuego_ diréctamente se carcajea.

Comment: Va a saber que sí o no. No puede estar en lo cierto sin probarlo.Y hay muchas otras palabras más.

Comment: @deStrangis Not to mention "me llamo Fénix, como el tagarote" ... OMG

Comment: @deStrangis: ¿Es usted el hispanohablante nativo? Y ¿no significa ´el tagarota´ la misma cosa que ´un bolsero´ en el español argentino?

Comment: @Manjusri Para un argentino promedio, un [tagarote](http://www.fotonatura.org/galerias/general/446492/) y un [bolsero](http://www.fotonatura.org/galerias/search/?txt=bolsero) son animales desconocidos (al menos por ese nombre)

Comment: @belisarius Según el diccionario, en Chile las palabras ´tagarote´ y ´bolsero´ no se aplica solamente a los pájaros.

Comment: @Manjusri Pero usted estaba hablando de pájaros y de Argentina ...

Comment: @Manjusri Soy hispanohablante nativo, de España, y la verdad es que no sé qué es un _tagarote_ ni un _bolsero_.

Comment: @deStrangis No es de uso común, pero evidentemente existe http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=tagarote

Comment: ok, pero decir _Me llamo Fénix, como el tagarote_ no creo que aclare nada a casi nadie.

Comment: @deStrangis Quizás ´Me llamo Fénix, como el protagonista de la película Santa Sangre por Alejandro Jodorowsky´ sueñe mejor (sin pensar en el nombre del guionista y la necesidad de explicar a la gente quien es Alejandro).

Comment: @belisarius: Pues, ¿cuál es la diferencia exacta entre una ave y un pájaro? A hablar de Chile y de Argentina, ambas son las países de la América del Sur. No creo que peronismo intelectual ni otras limitaciones del pensamiento sean fructiferos.

Answer (score 0):

Mi amigo me sugirió que tal vez la gente me malinterprete cuando digo "como el ave" — tal vez ella oiga "como" como la forma de "comer"!

```
Hola!  Soy Fénix, yo como el ave!
```

Comment: Nop.  "Como" está suficientemente claro en este contexto para un hispanoparlante

Answer (score 0):

Es un nombre poco comun,  es mas frecuente Felix,  y es pmuy probable que la gente no sepa de la existencia del mito del ave Fenix.

Answer (score -1):

Puede ser por varios motivos dependiendo de la región en la que te encuentres, pero por lo general puede sonar un tanto homosexual.

Comment: Es difícil encontrar un gato negro en una habitación oscura, sobre todo cuando no está. (c) Confucio.